How to use Sprig to filter by related entries using a dropdown
I have a Sprig board listing architect's projects, built in Craft 5. This is working pretty well with a search, date ordering of entries etc.
But — I am having trouble with a dropdown that I'd like to use to filter entries by means of selecting ONE of their related entries from the 'projectsCategories' section. This entry-relations tactic is used instead of the older 'categories' method.
At the moment I set things up like this
{% set projectsCategories = projectsCategories ?? [] %}

{# setup the project category query — works fine #}
{% set catQuery = craft.entries()
  .section('projectsCategories')
 %}

{% set cats =catQuery.all() %} 

{# Generate the entry query for the projects, also works well #}
{% set entryQuery = craft.entries({
    section: 'projects',
    relatedTo: projectsCategories,
}) %}

and this is the code for my dropdown category-filter selector on the Springboard, next to a search field (which works well!). This lists the 'projectsCategories' correctly, but NOTHING happens when I select / use the dropdown.
I am in the dark as to how to define the filter request here using Sprig. Any help / advice MUCH appreciated!
<label for="catFilter">Filter by category</label>
             
      <select sprig id="category" name="catFilter">

         <option value="">All</option>

         {% for category in cats %}

         <option value="{{category}}" >{{ category.title }}</option>
                            
         {% endfor %}
                        
      </select>


Figured it out! I hadn't given my select field the correct name!
This code now works, so I setup the default value and queries as before:
{% set projectsCategories = projectsCategories ?? [] %}

{% set catQuery = craft.entries()
  .section('projectsCategories')
 %}

{% set cats =catQuery.all() %} 

{% set entryQuery = craft.entries({
    section: 'projects',
    relatedTo: projectsCategories,
}) %}

then the key bit — putting the correct name value to match the  'projectsCategories' variable
<select sprig id="category" name="projectsCategories">
    
   <option value="">All</option>
    
   {% for category in cats %}
    
   <option value="{{category}}" >{{ category.title }}</option>
                                
   {% endfor %}
                            
 </select>

I can now filter by related entries...
Thanks again to @ben-croker for his videos, I should have watched the Sprig Filters / 2. Setting Default Values clip more closely, it explains how to name select fields...
https://putyourlightson.com/sprig/videos

In this case {{ category }} would be outputting the title of the category, but that can't be used as a relatedTo param. If you update it to <option value="{{ category.id }}"> it should work.

thanks for looking @revlis  — unfortunately that does not work...
